# Python - Iterator is going character by character, not line by line (when multiprocessing)

Tags: python, iterator, multiprocessing

I'm trying to iterate through a list of URLs, but the output I'm getting is character by character, not line by line. When running without multiprocessing, it works perfect. However, when I attempt to multi-process, it starts reading character by character. Why is this?

I've read up extensively on how to read line by line, and it looks to me as I'm doing it correctly. Where am I going wrong? It works perfectly without multiprocessing.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import multiprocessing

def findAdmin(URLList):
    # Loops through links
    for link in URLList:
        print (link)

# Multi-processing worker
def mp_worker(URLList):
    findAdmin(URLList)

# Multi-processing handler
def mp_handler(URLList):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    p.map(mp_worker, URLList)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    URLList = open('sites.txt','r')
    mp_handler(URLList)
    ## When running just findAdmin(URLList), the program works flawlessly.
    # findAdmin(URLList)
```

So, I must be doing something wrong regarding multiprocessing. But I just can't figure out what it is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `p.map(mp_worker, URLList)` submits jobs to the pool with each *element* of `URLList` as a worker argument, not with the whole `URLList`. Also, that's not a list.

Comment: It's a file, and it's trying to read by each element. I understand, now.

How could I code a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map()` runs `mp_worker` on **each** entry in URLList - the for loop is unnecessary. Change `findAdmin` to:

```
def findAdmin(URLList):
    print (link)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I just tried this - and get the same problem.
It seems not to change anything.

Comment: See update - the foor loop is unnecessary when using `map`

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks so much for your help.